# How to efficiently determine if a graph contains an (a, b)-edge?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Let $G$ be a graph.  The degree $d_G(v)$ of a vertex $v$ in $G$ is the number of edges that are incident to $v$.  An edge $uv$ in $G$ is called an $(a, b)$-edge if $d_G(u) = a$ and $d_G(v) = b$. Clearly, if an edge is an $(a,b)$-edge, then it is also a $(b,a)$-edge.

I would like to check if a graph contains an $(a, b)$-edge and return `True` if it does; otherwise, return `False`. I've written the following code, but an edge uses `VertexDegree` four times, so  I am wondering if there's a better solution.

```
containsEdgeQ[graph_, a_, b_] := 
 AnyTrue[EdgeList[
   graph], (VertexDegree[graph, First[#]] == a && 
      VertexDegree[graph, Last[#]] == 
       b) || (VertexDegree[graph, First[#]] == b && 
      VertexDegree[graph, Last[#]] == a) &]

graph = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 1, 6 <-> 7, 
   7 <-> 8, 8 <-> 9}]

containsEdgeQ[graph, 2, 3]  (*False*)
containsEdgeQ[graph, 1, 2]  (*True*)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[edgeDegrees, containsEQ]

edgeDegrees = Extract[VertexDegree[#][[Ordering @ VertexList @ #]], 
 Map[List] @ MapApply[List] @ EdgeList @ #, Sort] &;

containsEQ = MemberQ[Sort @ {#2,#3}] @ edgeDegrees @ # &;
```

***Examples:***

```
containsEQ[graph, 2, 3] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0000118813, False}
> ```

```
containsEdgeQ[graph, 2, 3] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0000255705, False}
> ```

```
containsEQ[graph, 2, 1]  // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000011866, True}
> ```

```
containsEdgeQ[graph, 2, 1]  // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0000198857, True}
> ```

Comment: Can you try to test this graph `g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}]`. It looks not well if you try `containsEQ [g,2,3]`

Comment: `containsEQ[g, 2, 3]` gives `False` as it should, no?

Comment: The undirected edge {2,3} is a (2,3)-edge (also is a (3,2)-edge) since the vertex 2 has degree three and the vertex 3 has degree two.

Comment: My function `containsEdgeQ[g, 2, 3]`  or `containsEdgeQ[g, 2, 3] ` gives `True`. It is right.

Comment: ah I see! will update with a fix.

Comment: @licheng, updated with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

This outputs all `(a,b)` degree edges (each edge is listed twice - as `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`):

```
graph = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 1, 6 <-> 7, 
    7 <-> 8, 8 <-> 9}];
am = Normal@AdjacencyMatrix[graph];
edgedegree={Count[am[[All, #[[1]]]], 1], Count[am[[#[[2]], All]], 1]} & /@ 
 Position[am, 1]
```

---

```
{{2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2},
{2, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}}
```

So you can then use it like:

```
MemberQ[edgedegree, {1, 2}]
```

---

```
True
```